# How do I to make a second monitor work as second desktop?

Tags: monitor

I have laptop `HP Compaq 610` on Intel, and I want to add an additional monitor. I would like this monitor to be a second desktop and not a part of the current desktop, because my laptop resolution is `16:9` and monitor is `16:10`

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for MultiseatX.  It's documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX).

It's a little dated and doesn't include LightDM.  It does have directions for KDM and workarounds for GDM.

Comment: You should note that this uses GDM (as was the fashion at the time) and hasn't been updated to LightDM.

Comment: But will it work under `ubuntu 11.04` ??

Comment: It would appear someone got it working on 11.04 using kdm

Answer (score 0):

I use the command line utility Disper (there's a PPA, add it with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:disper-dev/ppa && sudo apt-get update`, install `sudo apt-get install disper`) from the alt-F2 dialog box, `disper -e` will set your desktop to 'Extend mode' and `disper -c` will clone (mirror) again. `disper -s` to use only the standard display or `disper -S` to use the secondary display.

EDIT: changed -m (mirror) to -c (clone)

Comment: after `disper -e` i get `There is no matching crtc for the output
`, after `disper -m` was `Usage: disper [options] (-l|-s|-c|-e|-p|-i)`, `disper -s` switched off secound monitor, adn `disper -S` switched on secound monitor. So this doesnt work like I want

Comment: OK, I may have got the letters wrong - do `man disper` or `disper -h` to figure it out?

Comment: Dont work for me. Any letter

Comment: so disper -e doesn't extend, just gives errors? it's supposed to… you should report the bug to the disper development team, on launchpad

Comment: Also, what driver are you using? Default? Proprietary (through Additional Drivers)? Other?

Comment: Default I think

Comment: _Furrows brow_ Huh. Not sure how to help, sorry. It should be working just fine.

Comment: I was having problems with disper on 15.10 wily so I deleted .config/monitors.xml.  That didn't fix the problem so I ran "disper -s" and "disper -e" a couple more times and then it worked.